# Gradle: Converting a copy task from groovy to kotlin gradle script

Tags: kotlin, gradle, groovy, jar

I am stuck with converting a groovy gradle script to kotlin script. I am trying to use pf4j in my project and have started converting their example build.gradle to .gradle.kts. Example can be found here: https://github.com/pf4j/pf4j/blob/master/demo_gradle/plugins/build.gradle

Since I got stuck I am trying it just for one plugin right now, however their example is applying the task to all subprojects. So be aware of the difference.

So I tried to replace their build example with the following gradle.kts file:

```
val pluginClass: String by project
val pluginId: String by project
val pluginProvider: String by project
val version: String by project
val pf4jVersion: String by project

dependencies {
  implementation(project(":api"))
    implementation("org.pf4j:pf4j:${pf4jVersion}")
    annotationProcessor("org.pf4j:pf4j:${pf4jVersion}")
}


val buildPluginArchive = task("plugin", Jar::class) {
    manifest {
        attributes["Plugin-Class"] = pluginClass
        attributes["Plugin-Id"] = pluginId
        attributes["Plugin-Version"] = version
        attributes["Plugin-Provider"] = pluginProvider
    }

    archiveBaseName.set("plugin-${pluginId}")

    into("classes") {
        from(sourceSets.main.get().output)
    }
    dependsOn(configurations.runtimeClasspath)
    into("lib") {
        from({
            configurations.runtimeClasspath.get().filter { it.name.endsWith("jar") }.map { zipTree(it) }
        })
    }
    archiveExtension.set("zip")
}

tasks {
    "build" {
        dependsOn(buildPluginArchive)
    }
}
```

And it works and generates a zip, but the contents do not match the original. Firstly the lib folder does not only contain jar files, but also a folder structure (and more important a META-INF folder with MANIFEST.MF file that confuses the plugin loader). And it is missing the MANIFEST.MF in the classes/META-INF folder.

[image: Contents of plugin zip generated with original build configuration]
[image: Contents of plugin zip generated with my code]

I suspect the issue being somwhere with this configuration in the original build.gradle:

```
into('classes') {
    with jar
}
```

I just could not find any meaningful documentation about what "with jar" actually does or how to replicate the behavior in gradle.kts.

How can I get the same output as the demo with a gradle.kts configuration?

Answer (score 1):

> I just could not find any meaningful documentation about what "with jar" actually does

`with` is a method from the `Jar` task type. See the [method details](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.bundling.Jar.html#N23E7D) section of the `Jar` task, scroll to the bottom and you'll find information the `with` method. It's signature is:

```
CopySpec with(CopySpec... sourceSpecs)
```

Now if you were to look at the [API documentation](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/tasks/bundling/Jar.html) for `Jar`, you'll see that `with` actually comes from [`CopySpec`](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/file/CopySpec.html#with-org.gradle.api.file.CopySpec...-) which `Jar` implements thanks to its super class.

The `jar` part in `with jar` is referring to the task named *jar* which is created by the Java plugin.

With all of that said, a more idiomatic approach for the `with` part would be:

```
tasks {
    val plugin by registering(Jar::class) {
        into("classes") {
            with(jar.get())
        }
    }
    build {
        dependsOn(plugin)
    }
}
```

Comment: This works. I had to slightly adapt it to work as replacement for my code where i used 
```
into("classes") {
        with(tasks.named<Jar>("jar").get())
}
```
However the issue with the different file structure still remains.
So probably this copy spec was already correct, but the other one needs to be fixed to include jars.

Edit: just after writing this I figured out that I have to remove `.map { zipTree(it) }`